# Redefine bean in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts, javabeans

I have a (kind of luxury) problem.

We have some code in our JSP to check whether a user can delete an entry in the DB or not. Basically the creator and every Admin User has the right to do so. And the code works fine, but the IDE prints out an error and since I / we don't like these red alerts in the IDE, I'd like to know how to avoid this error.

I have an example code here:

```
<bean:define id="canDelete">false</bean:define>
<bean:define id="isOwner"><!-- Get some data --></bean:define>
<logic:equal value="true" name="isOwner">
    <bean:define id="canDelete">true</bean:define>
</logic:equal>
<logic:equal value="true" scope="request" name="isAdmin">
    <bean:define id="canDelete">true</bean:define>
</logic:equal>
<logic:equal value="true" name="canDelete">
    <!-- Write delete link -->
</logic:equal>
```

Edit:
The IDE (MyEclipse Pro 2014) says: **Duplicate local variable *canDelete***

Comment: what is the error printed out ?

Comment: Could you show the errors you see in the IDE?

Comment: IMO you should be setting stuff like that in the Java layer anyway. I don't know if Eclipse has line-level inspection overrides like IntelliJ does, if not, you'll probably have to live with it until you wrap up stuff like that in a custom tag, or put it somewhere better.

Comment: The problem here is that we are working with an internal company framework, so it had to be done like this.
We fixed this now, so this construct is no longer needed, but I'd really like to know for myself too.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same thing in my project's JSP code.
From the spec:

> USAGE NOTE - There is a restriction in the JSP 1.1 Specification that disallows using the same value for an id attribute more than once in a single JSP page. Therefore, you will not be able to use bean:define for the same bean name more than once in a single page.

So it seems like they're saying that you "can't" define the same bean twice, **because the JSP spec says you can't reuse the id.**

I checked the code, and the end result of processing the bean:define tag is this call

```
super.pageContext.setAttribute(this.id, value, inScope);
```

which results in something like this for the page scope (the default)

```
this.mPage.put(name, attribute)
```

So it does what we want it to do, it just antagonizes the JSP spec.